# Why does git merge ignore deleted files? Can I enforce deletions from the source branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging, git-merge-conflict

I'm trying to set up an automatic merge/build system between two project branches, but I'm having trouble with deletions not coming over in my merges. Here's the setup.

I develop on the **main** branch - add, modify, and delete files. All changes committed to **main**.

I have a second **release** branch where the latest work from **main** is merged in, and a build is made and published.

When I perform the merge - `git merge --no-commit -s recursive -Xtheirs main` (run from **release**) - most things merge over well with a preference for items coming from **main**. However, files *deleted* on **main** do *not* get deleted on **release**.

I think this is just how git merge works - if there's no actual conflict, git just keeps the file on **release**, no deletion. But I need it to be gone. Are there any commands I can run to make this happen? Or can I do it manually somehow?

---

**Update - fun detail:** Environment seems to make a difference here. This works as expected on my laptop (things are deleted through the merge), but it's failing when it runs as a Github Action. Sorry if that makes this a totally different issue.

Comment: It turns out this was a totally different problem having to do with submodules and merging between shallow clones. I was a fool - A FOOL! - to leave out that info in the question because it's a totally different problem than asked.

Short story -- Fetch deeper than 1 if you're trying to merge. Then submodules won't be a pain and cause conflicts, and the merge will complete - which results in deleting the appropriate files! Sigh... coding is hard sometimes, y'all.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a commit on main that includes the deleted files.

```
rm file1 file2
git add .
git commit -m "Delete file1 file2"
git checkout release
git merge --no-commit -s recursive -Xtheirs main
```

The deleted files should no longer exist on the release branch.

Comment: Oh, I do that. No issues making commits haha. Sorry, it seemed like a common-sense step, but I suppose this is a help forum. Gotta be clear. Will update.